# PHP Encryption Compatible with C# Encryption

Tags: c#, php, .net, encryption

i have this c# encryption code:

```
 public class Cryptor_Engine
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypt a string using dual encryption method. Return a encrypted cipher Text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toEncrypt">string to be encrypted</param>
    /// <param name="useHashing">use hashing? send to for extra secirity</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, string key, bool useHashing)
    {
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

        System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
        if (useHashing)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// DeCrypt a string using dual encryption method. Return a DeCrypted clear string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherString">encrypted string</param>
    /// <param name="useHashing">Did you use hashing to encrypt this data? pass true is yes</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string Decrypt(string cipherString, string key, bool useHashing)
    {
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);

        System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
        //Get your key from config file to open the lock!
        //string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String));

        if (useHashing)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

        tdes.Clear();
        return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
    }
}
```

The above code encrypts and decrypts text based on a provided key. i need a compatible php code that will give me the same key as the above algorithm? Will be possible to use both php and c# to have similar encrypted text?

Comment: Maybe with an external encrypt system you will be more sure. Otherwise you need to try and see if there are differences.

Comment: I edited my answer to include encryption as well as decryption, let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Encryption

Firstly, if `$useHashing` is true, we need to run the MD5 algorithm on `$key`

```
function encrypt($toEncrypt, $key, $useHashing) {
    if ($useHashing) {
        $key = md5($key);
    }
```

Next, we need to pad it using the PKCS7 algorithm. With PKCS7, the last byte of the string specifies the padding length, so we need to work out how much padding is required, and then add it.

```
    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $len = strlen($toEncrypt);
    $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
    $toEncrypt .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
```

Next, we do the encryption using the Mcrypt extension.

```
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $toEncrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

Lastly, encode the encrypted string as Base64.

```
    return base64_encode($encrypted);
```

So the complete function looks like:

```
function encrypt($toEncrypt, $key, $useHashing) {
    if ($useHashing) {
        $key = md5($key);
    }

    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $len = strlen($toEncrypt);
    $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
    $toEncrypt .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $toEncrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
```

#### Decryption

Firstly you receive the encrypted cipher as Base64, so you need to decode it.

```
function decrypt($cipherString, $key, $useHashing) {
    $decoded = base64_decode($cipherString);
    ...
```

Then, if `useHashing` is true, we need to run the md5 algorithm on the key.

```
    if ($useHashing) {
        $key = md5($key);
    }
```

Now we have our key and decoded string, we can actually decrypt the data.

```
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

`$decrypted` contains the decrypted string, with padding. To remove the padding we need to find the integer value of the last byte:

```
    $len = strlen($decrypted);
    $pad = ord($decrypted[$len-1]);
```

Now `$pad` is an integer which specifies how large the padding is, so simply return the part of the string before the padding.

```
    return substr($decrypted, 0, $len - $pad);
```

So putting it all together, we have:

```
function decrypt($cipherString, $key, $useHashing) {
    $decoded = base64_decode($cipherString);

    if ($useHashing) {
        $key = md5($key);
    }

    $decrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

    $len = strlen($decrypted);
    $pad = ord($decrypted[$len-1]);

    return substr($decrypted, 0, $len - $pad);
}
```

#### Security

If at all possible, you should [look at using AES, rather than 3DES](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/security-comparsion-of-3des-and-aes) and [a more secure cipher mode than ECB](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/225/should-i-use-ecb-or-cbc-encryption-mode-for-my-block-cipher).